# Cache size exceeds phone capacity

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, cache

What is going on here? (please see attached screen shot).

This is a Galaxy S5 Mini. Totally stock rom, never rooted. I have recently restored it to factory settings in an effort to overcome a fast draining battery.

Apps are complaining about lack of space, but based on this I believe that to be false (also, I have put almost nothing on the phone).

Anyone have any ideas on the best way to fix this?

[image: storage screenshot]
<sup>Storage (click to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: Install [App Cache Cleaner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.infolife.cache&hl=) and check what apps use the cache. It'll make analysing easier.

Comment: @SarpSTA should be sufficient to [boot into recovery mode](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/recovery-mode/info) and "wipe cache", no additional app needed for that. It's even possible to [Clear Caches from ADB](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/110426/16575). But right, if you want to *analyze* before, that's a different thing. Though it will be hard to install an additional app with the storage already full ;)

Comment: @Izzy I didn't suggest him to do that so he can wipe cache, I suggested it to figure out the app that generates that amount of cached data.

Comment: @SarpSTA I just tried to figure how that can be done without an app (as obviously, OP hardly can install additional apps). And I found a solution. If the device is rooted, analysis can be done via ADB: `adb shell su -c "for dir in /data/data/*/*cache; do du -sk $dir; done"` would list the apps having cache with the cache size (in kB) and their package names.

Comment: @Izzy seems useful! OP should give a go to it.

Comment: @SarpSTA I've summed it all up in an answer. Though it's clear OP doesn't have root access, I've included the "root variants" (maybe useful for other readers) – but also showed a manual non-root variant to "analyse and clear selectively". Hope it's helpful!

Comment: Thank both - I will experiment with the proposed solutions and I will see if I get anywhere. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fully agree the storage screen shows "incoherent data" (more cache used than there's storage available), so it must have miscalculated.

As your device is already complaining about "low storage", I assume installing additional apps is not an option. If your device were rooted (which it is not), you could figure which app(s) is/are responsible for "high cache consumption", utilizing ADB:

```
adb shell su -c "for dir in /data/data/*/*cache; do du -sk $dir; done"
```

This shows the directory (including the app's package name) and the size of cache used in kB. Snipped of example output (from one of my devices):

```
2224    /data/data/com.feedr/app_cache
32      /data/data/com.feedr/cache
32      /data/data/com.fsck.k9/app_sslcache
32      /data/data/com.fsck.k9/cache
```

Without root, there might be ways achieving similar results via tools like "package manager" (`pm`) – but I couldn't figure that yet. If the culprit was found with the above command, you can selectively free its cache running `rm -rf` against the specified cache directory (again as root), or just clear the cache altogether (see [Clear Caches from ADB](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/110426/16575)). Clearing the cache completely doesn't require root and is possible via most (stock and custom) recoveries, and also (stock, custom, root or not) via the `fastboot erase cache` command.

If the above is not possible for you, and you're still able to install apps (maybe after deleting another installed app), you could go [the way SarpSTA recommended](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/129257/16575#comment-160863) and install a cache manager to check. If that's not possible either, the "long way" would be going to *Settings › Apps* and walking the "All" tab – opening each app's page and see how much "cache" is printed for it, manually hitting the "clear cache" button for "heavy eaters".