# How to put LG G2 in fastboot mode?

Tags: fastboot, lg-g2

Is there any way to get an **LG G2** (running the latest version of stock software, Lollipop 5.0.2) in **fastboot mode**?  None of the methods listed anywhere online work for me.  I'm getting the feeling that it's not an option on this device, but I've heard no definitive confirmation of that.

Here's what I've tried and has not helped:

- Turning the device off, holding down power and volume down buttons, releasing them when the LG logo displays, and holding them down again to power up.  This brings the phone into `Factory data reset` mode, in which the only option is to `Erase all user data & restore default settings`.
- Turning the device off, holding the volume up, and plugging a connected USB cable into the phone.  This brings the phone into `Download Mode`.
- `adb reboot fastboot`.  This reboots the phone normally.
- `adb reboot bootloader`.  This also reboots the phone normally.

(If you're wondering why I need to get into Fastboot: [How to Clear Caches in LG G2 Running Lollipop 5.0.2](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/110325/how-to-clear-caches-in-lg-g2-running-lollipop-5-0-2).)

To be clear, I mean that `fastboot devices` lists nothing when I do any of the above methods.  But `adb` is working.

Comment: I thought only Samsung devices had download mode. Anyway download mode should be fastboot mode

Answer (score 4):

Download mode may appear prior to fastboot mode.

1. Boot down the phone
2. Keep holding down `Volume Up` button.
3. Put a USB cable that is connected to a PC in to phone.
4. Continue holding `Volume Up` button throughout download mode until fastbood mode appears and you can release the `Volume Up` button.

Extra: [Here's the how-to video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kcFtnZZ7I1U)

Comment: Can you explain the issue in [this existing answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/130267/96277)?

Comment: @Firelord Should other answers suck for me to provide an answer?

Comment: Not that I understand what you wrote in comments, I mentioned that answer and sought your input because your answer is more or less covered in that existing answer. Adding redundancy on a page doesn't help.

Comment: @Firelord One difference is that, that answer says Power Button should also be held down, mine doesn't.

Comment: This puts the phone in download mode, not fastboot mode, so it doesn't answer the question in any ways. It isn't even mentioned if download mode is a complete replacement for fastboot mode or not. First I also confused the two, but `fastboot devices` doesn't recognise an LG G2 in download mode.

Answer (score 1):

Per [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/lgg2/comments/29jx7w/how_to_enter_fastboot_mode_on_the_lg_g2/), the fastboot is entered in when boot partitions get corrupted. For obvious reasons, I'm not overly thrilled about testing this theory by corrupting my boot partitions :)

Answer (score 1):

SarpSTA's answer is correct, but if you're on Windows you may need to install qualcomm drivers for some versions of the LG G2. I had to do this for the ls980 as per [this post](http://androidforums.com/threads/hard-brick-lg-g2-qhsusb_bulk-but-no-partitions-detected.934856/#post-7096537):

> Start by installing qualcomm drivers on your windows machine to better
>   detect which mode your phone is in right now:
>
> https://www.dropbox.com/s/3hovx8h7nauy7e6/Qcomm_Drivers.zip?dl=0
>
> Unzip into a regular folder onto desktop. Plug in device and go to
>   device manager. Find device that is phone, right click and update
>   driver. Choose option to provide your own driver and point to the
>   location of the entire folder of qualcomm drivers on the desktop. When
>   done, note how the device is described in device manger. It should be
>   more specific now. It sounds like you may be in a QDLoader 9008 mode
>   since no partitions are showing up for you.

Even though it said my drivers appear to be up to date, it would not boot into fastboot mode until after attempting to update from this Qualcomm_Drivers package. Prior to that it would mount a bunch of drives.

Answer (score 0):

1. Power off your LG device;
2. Connect your USB cable to your computer, but not your phone
3. Press and hold the Power and Volume Up keys simultaneously. Hold for about 5 to 8 seconds. Now connect the other end of the USB cable to your phone;
4. Done!
   If it worked, you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had the same problem on my LG G2 mini.
This command worked for me:
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/laf
By doing so, the phone can't enter Download mode and enters Fastboot mode instead.
Use with caution though, I don't know what this really does to the device!

Comment: I believe this corrupts your partition so that your device automatically enters fastboot. I am just guessing though. `dd` usually overwrites stuff.

Comment: this used to be a workaround for older devices. meanwhile fastboot seems to removed completely

Answer (score 0):

all you have to do is hold down the volume down button and the power button and then plug in the USB cord real fast as it starting up and then we'll go straight into fastboot mode